# How can I update a view with or without a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-view

I notice an issue about MS SQL command.
The company's database have a View that is based on 5 tables.
Here is the structure/code for the `email_view_test`:

```
create view [dbo].[email_view_test]
as
SELECT
    fi.fund_no,
    kw.key_no,
    kw.key_title,
    f.fac_id,
    f.email,
    fi.agency_no,
    fi.cfda_no,
    fi.cont_url,
    fi.cont_url2,
    fi.due_date,
    fi.due_note,
    fi.entry_dt,
    fi.fundtext,
    fi.prog_title,
    fi.sponcode,
    fi.sect,
    fak.Status
FROM
    dbo.ff_fundinfo fi
left join ff_fundkey fk on fk.fund_no=fi.fund_no
left join ff_keyword kw on kw.key_no=fk.key_no
left join ff_fackey fak on fak.key_no=kw.key_no
left join  ff_faculty f on f.fac_id=fak.fac_id

where due_date>getdate()
GO
```

**I have tried to update the Status to 'sent' by below code:**

```
UPDATE email_view_test 
SET Status = 'sent'  where email= 'lilirasouliha@gmail.com' and fund_no= '99998'
```

**But for some reason the `fund_no` does not work in the update (It just ignored)**

**codes:**

```
select top 10 * from ff_fackey where status='sent' order by key_no

select top 10 fund_no,key_no,fac_id,status from email_view_test 
where status='sent' order by fund_no
```

**Screenshot of the results:**

[image]

The issue appeared here as you can see, I wanted the Status updated only for `fund_no` of `99998` but this updated for all `fund_no` (in our case is only `99998` and `99999`) I assume the issue is because I have the status in Table `ff_fackey` . Maybe I have to change it to somewhere else? I am authorized to change the status and move it anywhere if that is the case.

I think this caused since I am trying to update one table through View but I am using two different columns in different tables.

Here is also the structor of all tables that I have :

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

I also think about a solution to use join in my update code, But it does not work and give error: (I would be appreciate if this code can be fixed if this is the case)

```
UPDATE email_view_test v inner join ff_fundinfo f on v.fund_no=f.fund_no
SET v.Status = 'sent'  where v.email= 'lilirasouliha@gmail.com' and v.fund_no= '99998' ;
```

UPDATE of above code:
I noticed the above code issue's syntax, The code should be like below (bu it still ignore the `fund_no` to update it)

```
UPDATE email_view_test 
SET Status = 'sent'   
from email_view_test join ff_fundinfo on email_view_test.fund_no=ff_fundinfo.fund_no
where email_view_test.fund_no= '99998' and email= 'lilirasouliha@gmail.com'
```

UPDATE 2: I think the issue is with my view the way retrieve the data including status, I think I should retrieve the data in another way but not sure how to write a SQL command which retrieves only the fak.status that is correct one.

I would be appreciate for any help, advice to make this update work with manipulating the place of Status in may tables or changing the update SQL code.

Comment: Well....the column Status is not in your view. How could it possibly know what you want to do?

Comment: The solution is to add the Status column to your view OR update the base table directly

Comment: I do apologize, I already added that but I put a wrong code in question. I updated the code. Thank you so much for the reminding me